# How to refactor static constructor to enable unit / acceptance testing

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

In my acceptance test for a service, I'm setting up the testee as follows:

```
var dataService = A.Fake<IDataService>();
this.domainRepository = A.Fake<IDomainRepository>();
var dbContextArticles = A.Fake<IDbContextArticles>();

this.testee = new DomainService(dataService, this.domainRepository, dbContedbContextArticles xtArtikel);
```

This setup unfortunately fails, because.

1. The `DomainService` class inherits from `BaseDataService`.
2. `BaseDataService` has a static constructor that looks like this:
   `DbContext.LoadTranslations();`
3. And `DbContext.LoadTranslations();` looks like this:
   `using (DomainEntities entities = new DomainEntities(DbBase.ConnectionString))
   { ... }`

So when I create an instance of `DomainService` it fails, because of couse in my acceptance test there is no connection string defined since I don't want to use the real database.

According to a comment, the translations have to be loaded in the static constructor or otherwise it gets loaded 8 times when searching for an article...

- Do you have any proposals how I can refactor this so that the acceptance test uses a fake context?

I tried introducing a `ContextFactory` but the problem is, that the static constructor of `BaseDataService` calls the static method `DbContext.LoadTranslations()` so I can't inject a `IContextFactory` into `DbContext` because this constructor isn't even called...

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can add an instance method on your `DomainService` (or `BaseDataService`) to do what your static constructor does. Then call this method when you instantiate your `DomainService`, from the outside (eg. `testee.LoadTranslations()`) or withing its constructor (more convenient if using a dependency injection). You can check for a flag to verify if it has already being loaded and a lock mechanism to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Hey @polkduran thanks for your answer. The problem is that the Translations should only be loaded once in the application. If I add the `LoadTranslations()` call to the constructor, it will be loaded every time when I create an instance of a Service that implements `BaseDataService`or not? How can I check for a flag in these circumstances?

Comment: You can either declare the flag as `static` (and your lock object as well) or create a dedicated class (service) as a singleton that holds the translation loading logic and call it at some point of your app/test initialization or pass it to your `DomainService`.

Comment: I would need to see more of the code to get the full picture but I think you need to replace the static initialization with a Singleton. Martin Fowler illustrates this idea here: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/StaticSubstitution.html